# Q: Hoffman Linear Algebra question 11 pg. 243, Elementary Canonical Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let N be a 
$2\times2$ complex matrix such that $N^{2} = 0.$ Prove that $N = 0$ or $N$ is similar over $C$ to

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right]\\$$

then  show that every $2\times2$ complex matrix is silimar to

$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & 0\\
0 & b
\end{array}\right]\\$ and $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & 0\\
1 & a
\end{array}\right]\\$

detail: Just using eigenvalues, eigenvectors and characteristic polynomial.

Comment: This is just the exercise you should go through on your own. $2\times 2$ matrices are friendly small, characteristic polynomials are quadratic, determinant is easily calculated ($ad-bc$). So that it could help you clear up these notions..

Comment: for the first part i notice that $x^{2}$ is the characterist polynomial of $N$, so $0$ are the only eigenvalues of $N$ but how i get a two basis from the characterist space of $0$ that bring me to the similar matrix of the exercise?